# Unable to resolve sdk.buildtools property value '18.1.0'

Tags: android, sdk, renderscript, build-tools

I'm getting this error and cannot compile my android program. Here is my *project.properties* file:

```
target=android-22
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=18.1.0
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was using Eclipse which was buggy and had problems cleaning and building the project sometimes. Changing to Android Studio which has much better support is helpful for anyone who is having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the sdk.buildtools version you have specified has been downloaded via the Android SDK Manager.

Build-Tools Version 18.1.0 is quite old and for me is no longer listed in the SDK Manager (see below). You should update your project to use a newer version of the Android build tools.

[image]